# How to set autocommit value to false in Oracle Data Source connection?

Tags: java, oracle, autocommit

Inserting values in Oracle 11g via JdbcTemplate-OracleDataSource injected via Spring config file. 
Transactions are done via @Transactional managed by DataSourceTransactionManager.

Question 1) How to set the autocommit value to false? Default value is true, I guess.
Following is the code snippet :

```
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.getBean("dataSourceBean");
    try {
        ds.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Autocommit " +ds.getConnection().getAutoCommit());
    } catch (SQLException e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `println` statement is giving `true` only.

Also printed the getAutoCommit value in insert method of the DAO class. There also is coming as true.

Question2) For unique constraint violation, I need to rollback.
In that case, `DuplicateKeyException` is thrown which is wrapped over SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.
So 
@Transactional(rollbackFor = ?.class) must have which Exception?

Comment: Ask only one question at a time.

Comment: The connection (or its proxy) might return true because the commit is handled automatically (by the container) and not by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Store it in a variable

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.getBean("dataSourceBean");
try {
    Connection con =ds.getConnection();
    con.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("Autocommit " +con.getAutoCommit());
} catch (SQLException e) {          
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you call the ds.getConnection() again , you get another connection from pool

2.Change Weblogic DataSource configuration
[Auto commit transactions if not explicitly committed or rolledback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525605/auto-commit-transactions-if-not-explicitly-committed-or-rolledback)

Comment: @ Mahdi Yes, this is what I found out just now. Is there a way to set the autocommit in the spring config itself? Using like this: <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">  
  <property name="databaseName" value="xx" />
  <property name="URL" value="xx" />
  <property name="user" value="xx" />
  <property name="password" value="xx" /> 
</bean>

Comment: <property name="defaultAutoCommit"><value>false</value></property>

Comment: <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" /> gives error. Tried with 'autoCommit', same error     org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'defaultAutoCommit' of bean class [oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource]

Answer (score 1):

Instead doing programmatically, check your connection pool has the option to set auto commit to false when returning connection from the pool. DBCP's [BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-2.0/index.html) has such option

Spring will do rollback if any RuntimeException is thrown .